# Using UDP broadcast for pods/peers discovery in Kubernetes

Tags: docker, networking, kubernetes, udp, peer-discovery

I need to use UDP broadcast for peer discovery.

Environment:

- `docker-desktop` with a single node Kubernetes cluster

My code looks as follows:

```java
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class MainApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        int inPort = Integer.parseInt(System.getenv("IN_PORT"));
        int outPort = Integer.parseInt(System.getenv("OUT_PORT"));
        String name = System.getenv("NAME");
        Client client = new Client(name, outPort);
        Server server = new Server(name, inPort);

        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        service.submit(client);
        service.submit(server).get();
    }


    static class Client implements Runnable {
        final String name;
        final int port;

        Client(String name, int port) {
            this.name = name;
            this.port = port;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(name + " client started, port = " + port);
            try (DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket()) {
                socket.setBroadcast(true);
                while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                    byte[] buffer = (name + ": hi").getBytes();

                    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length,
                            InetAddress.getByName("255.255.255.255"), port);
                    socket.send(packet);
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    System.out.println("packet sent");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }


    static class Server implements Runnable {
        final String name;
        final int port;

        Server(String name, int port) {
            this.name = name;
            this.port = port;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

            System.out.println(name + " server started, port = " + port);

            try (DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(port)) {

                byte[] buf = new byte[256];
                while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
                    socket.receive(packet);
                    String received = new String(packet.getData(), 0, packet.getLength());

                    System.out.println(String.format(name + " received '%s' from %s:%d", received,
                            packet.getAddress().toString(),
                            packet.getPort()));
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Kubernetes pod settings:

For `peer-1`:

```
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: p2p
          image: p2p:1.0-SNAPSHOT
          env:
          - name: NAME
            value: "peer-1"
          - name: IN_PORT
            value: "9996"
          - name: OUT_PORT
            value: "9997"
```

For `peer-2` :

```
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: p2p-2
          image: p2p:1.0-SNAPSHOT
          env:
          - name: NAME
            value: "peer-2"
          - name: IN_PORT
            value: "9997"
          - name: OUT_PORT
            value: "9996"
```

I used a different in/out ports for simplicity's sake. In reality, it should be the same port, e.g.: 9999

I see that each pod has a unique IP address

```
kubectl get pods -o wide

NAME                                READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE     IP          NODE             NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
p2p-deployment-2-59bb89f9d6-ghclv   1/1     Running   0          2m26s   10.1.0.38   docker-desktop   <none>           <none>
p2p-deployment-567bb5bd77-5cnsl     1/1     Running   0          2m29s   10.1.0.37   docker-desktop   <none>           <none>
```

Logs from `peer-1`:

```
peer-1 received 'peer-2: hi' from /10.1.0.1:57565
```

Logs from `peer-2`:

```
peer-2 received 'peer-1: hi' from /10.1.0.1:44777
```

Question: why `peer-1` receives UDP packets from `10.1.0.1` instead of `10.1.0.37` ?

If I log into `peer-2` container: `kubectl exec -it p2p-deployment-2-59bb89f9d6-ghclv -- /bin/bash`

Then

```
socat - UDP-DATAGRAM:255.255.255.255:9996,broadcast
test
test
...
```

in `peer-1` logs I see `peer-1 received 'test' from /10.1.0.1:43144`. 
Again why network address is `10.1.0.1` instead of `10.1.0.37`.

Could you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Note: when using the same port to send/receive UDP packets, some peer can receive a packet from its own IP address. In other words, a peer can only discover its own IP address but always gets `10.1.0.1` for packets received from other peers/pods

Comment: That is really the wrong way to do it. You use multicast for such things. Have the peers subscribe to a specific multicast group. Using multicast will not interrupt all the other hosts on the LAN (routers, printers, other PCs, etc.). Using broadcast is a mistake, and if you use it then you will not be able to add or convert to IPv6 because it does not have broadcast. Multicast is designed to only talk to a specific group of interested hosts that subscribe to the multicast group, but broadcast interrupts all the hosts on the LAN, interested or not.

Comment: Why do you need to manually implement peer discovery at all? Kubernetes manages the set of pods, and can directly be queried for the list of healthy peers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, UDP **broadcast** doesn't work as expected in Kubernetes infrastructure, however **multicast** works fine.

Thanks [Ron Maupin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3745413/ron-maupin) for suggesting multicast.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/dmgcodevil/22e50eb8f415602bb8d128fe28cdb209) you can find java code + kube config